# How to build dynamic map of all list and dictionary elements in json using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a json file and i have to write map dynamically like how many list and dictionary elements are there in json and how to reach there i.e find it ie where exactly it is.

**This is json file -**

```
    {
        "quiz": {
            "sport": {
                "q1": {
                    "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                    "options": [
                        "New York Bulls",
                        "Los Angeles Kings",
                        "Golden State Warriros",
                        "Huston Rocket"
                    ],
                    "answer": "Huston Rocket"
                },
               "q2" ... some more json,
               "q3" : [
                    "file" : {"none":"none"},
                    "type" : ["py", "txt"]
               ]
            }
        }
    }
```

**The output of this should be:**

```
quiz_q1   = @Object @1C                          @1C
            Quiz    sport first child of quiz    q1 first child of sport

quiz_type = @Object  @1C   @3C @2C
            Quiz     sport q3  type
```

Comment: Please share some code which you have tried till now.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried and what specific problems did you encounter?

Comment: @py_saad i dont know where to start. I am new in python. I only tried recursion to find how many list and dict type are there. thats it

Comment: @ekhumoro bro i have a json list and i have to find all the list and dict elements from parent node for eg in this json file quiz, how to reach to all the list and dict elements from there. I dont have any code. I dont know where to start